# Use specification with a list of expressions

Tags: java, spring

I need return from *binRepository* productBin which follows this specification:

- field "start" must be equals bin.getStart()
- field "end" must be equals bin.getEnd()
- field "binUse.acronym" must be equals some string

Note that BinUse is a class and acronym is your attribute.

```
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BIN_USE_ID", nullable = false)
    private BinUse binUse;

    @Column(name = "BIN_START")
    private Long start;

    @Column(name = "BIN_END")
    private Long end;
```

How I can search productBin with this threes requeriments? I have a list of this requeriments but CriteriaBuilder doesn't accept a predicate list.

```
ProductBin productBin = this.productBinRepository.findOne(new Specification<ProductBin>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<ProductBin> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
                List<Predicate> listPredicate = new ArrayList<>();
                listPredicate.add(cb.equal(root.get("start"), bin.getStart()));
                listPredicate.add(cb.equal(root.get("end"), bin.getEnd()));
                listPredicate.add(cb.equal(root.get("binUse.acronym"), BinUseAcronym.FPAN.toString()));

                return cb.and();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert to array

```
query.where(cb.and(listPredicate.toArray(new Predicate[listPredicate.size()])));
```